# Listings, literate, and space at the start of the line.

Tags: spacing, listings

I am trying to use the literate option to replace the prompt (`>>>`) and continuations (`...`) in python input with symbols that "hang" in the margin.  I can almost do this with something like `literate=*{>>>}{\llap{$\ggg$\hspace{5pt}}}{0}` etc. but am running into a few problems: If I use a length of `0` as above I get errors and, extra space is inserted before the listing creating an undesired indent (though as demonstrated below, I think setting the length to `0` will not help, even if I can prevent the errors).

I would appreciate any suggestions.  Here is a minimal example that almost almost works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  language=python,
  columns=flexible,
  frame=leftline,
  framexleftmargin=0pt,
  framesep=4pt,
  xleftmargin=5pt,
  literate=*{>>>}{\llap{\footnotesize$\ggg$\hspace{8pt}}}{1}
            {...}{\llap{$\cdots$\hspace{8pt}}}{1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Here is some python code:
\begin{lstlisting}
def f():
    """This is a function."""
    return 1
f()
\end{lstlisting}
This uses the doctest format, but has extra indentation:
\begin{lstlisting}
>>> def f():
...     """This is a function."""
...     return 1
>>> f()
1
\end{lstlisting}
This is even a problem without any output:
\lstset{%
  literate=*{>>>}{}{0}
            {...}{}{0}}
\begin{lstlisting}
>>> def f():
...     """This is a function."""
...     return 1
>>> f()
1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how to work around it:

```
...
literate=*{>>>}{\llap{\footnotesize$\ggg$\hspace{8pt}}}{-1}
          {...}{\llap{$\cdots$\hspace{8pt}}}{-1}}
...
```

Used a negative space as the third argument to `literate={<replace>}{<replacement text>}{<width>}`.

[image: Listings code with literate alteration]

Comment: Ugh! But a clever ugh none the less:-)  Since I am using flexible spacing the slight indent alignment is not much of an issue.  (Actually, on my machine it seems to even give the correct indent on these lines too, so I call this a solution.)  I am not really sure why using `-1` instead `0` works though...

Comment: Agreed. I tried to figure out something from the `listings` package code, in terms of what it does with the `<width>` parameters, without success. Quickly stopped searching after this work-around did the job.

Comment: It seems that `-1` is enough.  The extra space after `>>>` etc. is not needed (and actually seems to mess things up a bit).  Thanks!  (I retract my ugh.)

Comment: Is there any reason for the space `>>>{ }`?  It seems to mess up the spacing (between the `f` and `()` for example).  On my system it is not needed.

Comment: You're right - I didn't notice it at first; was more focussed on the margin than the actual code! I'll modify my answer to reflect that.